# Using python to post a test to API

Tags: python, http-post

```
import requests,json

verify='/users/myprofile/Downloads/.me/ca_bundle.crt'

data = {"Authorization": "Basic ODE2YzMzM2ZmYzUwNDg1MThlNTJmMWMyMWJiYzZhOTQ6NWExNDFhMGExNGI4NGQ2OWIyMjUxYTI2OGYwZDJlYjk="}

url = "https://api.pge.com/datacustodian/test/oauth/v2/token?grant_type=client_credentials"

response = requests.post(url, cert=('/users/David/Downloads/bei.me/private.key', data)

#print("status code", response.status_code)
```

Error i am getting:
File "SSLTest.py", line 12

```
                                           ^
```

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

How do i include my public cert when making a call to utility company's api? They had me submit my public certificate

Answer (score 0):

You should put:

```py
response = requests.post(url, cert='/users/David/Downloads/bei.me/private.key', data)
```

In addition:

CA Certificate are not mandatory for public websites

PS: your data variable looks like an header, so you might want:

```py
response = requests.post(url, cert='/users/David/Downloads/bei.me/private.key', headers=data)
```

Comment: its not an actual website (mine isnt) just a certificate to verify i am who say i am when i do the post its going to pge's website (they have my cert)

Comment: thanks, now i am getting requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.pge.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /datacustodian/test/oauth/v2/token?grant_type=client_credentials (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(9, '[SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3880)')))

Comment: Using the cert keyword will allow SSL protocol to work with specific self-created websites. You should not put your private key here. you can simply put: `response = requests.post(url,  headers=data)`

Comment: PGE requires a certificate for end to end communication with their API